# PHP + MySQL suddenly stops the query

Tags: php, mysql

I can't understand how and why my **mysql_query** command stops it's execution.
There are two arrays I work with:

1. routersTree (includes about 100 rows)
2. dates (includes about 30 cells)

Here the code:

```
while ($i <= count($routerTree)){
    $currentRouter = $routerTree["router_$i"];
    echo "<td>$i</td>";
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($dates); $j++) { 
        $sql = "SELECT indications.id_device FROM indications LEFT JOIN routers ON indications.id_device = routers.id_device WHERE routers.id_router = $currentRouter[id_router] AND date(indications.dateField) = '$dates[$j]' ORDER BY routers.id_device";
        if ($res = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))) {
            echo "<td>$res</td>";
            }
        else {
            echo "<td>error</td>";
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

It stops my cycle after 18-th row, but there are about 82 cycles more to do.
My guess is, that there is a small timeout for mysql_query command.
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: NEVER chain database calls like that. You're simply assuming nothing could ever go wrong, which is exactly the WRONG attitude to have. even if your sql syntax is 100% perfect, there's literally an infinite number of other reasons for failure to occur. always check for success/failure at EVERY db call. if the query fails, it returns boolean false to num rows, which then also fails.

Comment: Print the query out as well as the row number, when you see the error you will be given the SQL it is using too, you should be able to figure out what is causing the error then.

Comment: @MarcB I made an if statement to check if the result is true but still have the same problem :( Or may be I misunderstand you.

Comment: And database queries inside of a loop are not good practice either. You should make _one_ query to gather all the data you need, and then loop over that data to generate whatever output format you need.

Comment: @CBroe Hm, but how to do it if i need this cycles to pass data like date and router id?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after continue finding the solution of my problem **I finaly found one**. So easy and so fast... **The problem was in PHP timeout**. I just added into my **settings.php** file next entry:

```
ini_set ('max_execution_time', 0);
```

The default value is 30 seconds. 0 means the infinite loop. But be careful with this thing. Rise the value for your needs, but try not to use infinite loop.

Comment: Better is to "reset" the value in the loop. If one iteration takes 1-2 seconds, then put this `ini_set` command inside the loop with value `10`.

Comment: Well I agree with you and thought about it, but all depends on needs. My program needs it almost everywhere, so more productive is to use infinite timeout for the whole program.